# How to check if a class have a specific constructor?

Tags: c++, c++20

I have the following source code:

```
std::string s;
std::string_view sv(s.begin(), s.end());
```

that compiles with MSVC and GCC, but does not compile with Apple Clang.

What is the right way to write a function like

```
template< class It >
constexpr std::string_view make_string_view( It first, It last );
```

that would compile with both C++17 and C++20 and use new `std::string_view` constructor accepting two iterators if possible?

Comment: Sidenote, if your goal was to capture the view of the entire string, then you can simply call `std::string_view sv(s)`.

Answer (score 5):

You would need to check at compile time that:

1. Iterators are of random access
2. Their value_type is `std::string_view::value_type`

You may check by using the `std::iterator_traits` class, `std::is_same_v` type trait and `static_assert`.
Having that done you could calculate the distance from first to last (by using `std::distance`) and call the following `std::string_view` constructor:

```
constexpr basic_string_view( const CharT* s, size_type count );
```

For `s`, you could pass `std::addressof(*first)`, and for the count the result of the `std::distance` call.

Comment: The iterators need to be _contiguous_, not just random access.